# 404 error on logout with WAR exploded to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

My application works fine when I use embedded Tomcat (with IntelliJ) but when I deploy WAR file on Tomcat 8 one of my URLs response with 404 (I can sign in into my application but logout with URL responses with 404). This problem doesn't happen when I use IntelliJ with Tomcat.

My POM file:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Config file:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable();
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable();

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

**Update**

I change to Tomcat 9 and I still have the problem.

**Update_2**

I have JSF view

Comment: 404 is a page not found - so the URL returning the error is the one not found? Perhaps sharing the URL in question will help get an answer.

Comment: myApp_war_exploded/logout    returning 404

Comment: Context root is created after the war name, is the war named `myApp_war_exploded.war`? Case sensitive as I recall.

Comment: I think the 'exploded' part of the name is IntelliJ specific? As @LMC says, tomcat will just unpack the WAR to it's own name and that probably does not include 'exploded' in there. So I suspect somewhere in the application config you have defined a reference to the logout page as being on ``myApp_war_exploded/logout``? I think it should just be a relative link (not including the app name) or try and derive the app name from the application context itself as the app name (and thus deployed URL) does not have to be the same as the application WAR name.

Comment: i try this :      `http.logout().logoutUrl("/myApp_war_exploded/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");`                                  
   and try this :                     `http.logout().logoutUrl("/myApp_war_exploded/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/myApp_war_exploded"); `                                                                                                                            doesn't help

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/myApp_war_exploded`                         this is my url

Comment: I'm not a spring boot expert, but I would think you do not mention the WAR name in any of those URLs. The app should figure out the relative URL itself. So try ``http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");``

Comment: i tried this too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out tomcat has promblem with api without page then i create a button and call the method :

```
 public void logout(){
    userAuthService.logout();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
         .invalidateSession();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
         .redirect("login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```